# Support only two languages in my Android app

Tags: android, locale, onconfigurationchanged

My android application only needs to support English and Spanish. Default is English. But if I change the language of my phone to any other language, say, 
French, still my app considers it as a configuration change and onCreate of the activity gets called. I have not handled android:configChanges because I want my app to handle the language changes automatically but just for English and Spanish.

What changes do I need to make so that app only handles English and Spanish and if any other language is selected, it should ignore the change and just resume.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the answer? I'm facing this issue too! I don't want my app support all languages, but the CH Play said my app support 83 languages :(

Answer (score 1):

Your folder structure will change as follows -

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
```

If you decide to support a Right to Left language, you need to choose `Force RTL layout` from the developer setting and check how your app behaves for `RTL languages`.
Check out this link for more info https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: If you think the answer worked for you, can you accept it as answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, my question is I do not want my app configuration to change if any language other than English or Spanish is selected in phone. Now, even if I select Dutch, it considers it as configuration change and calls onCreate of my activity. Let me know if it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The folder res/values is a DEFAULT directory and the others are just "in case of language". So everything I had to do was to switch the english to /res/values and the other language goes to res/values-es

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, my question is I do not want my app configuration to change if any language other than English or Spanish is selected in phone. Now, even if I select Dutch, it considers it as configuration change and calls onCreate of my activity. Let me know if it is clear.